# Transfer weebly site to a new address and keep slideshow

Tags: weebly

I built a site on weebly and archived and exported all of the files associated with it.  When I tried the files with the new site (basically just needed to change addresses), the slideshow no longer worked.  That's when I found out via google that this is a known problem, but all of the posts on it are over two years old.  Has anyone figured out a way around this?

Usually I would include code on SO, but there is so much that you'll have to let me know what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I put my weebly site inside an iframe on the "authorized site".  No one can link to any of the individual pages and I couldn't figure out the iframeresizer, so there is awkward space at the end of some pages.  It's terrible.

But the rest of the group can easily go into weebly and edit any of the pages, which saves me a lot of time and responsibility.  Plus, of course, the precious slide show works.